# Moving a view acording to music

Tags: android, android-layout

i got a image view

[image]

that

goes over this one

[image]

and i want to scale it acording to a media player music ( if is posible to the bass)
the idea its to try to make looks like a speaker.
I found this, may be ultil

```
public class Visulizer extends Activity {

TextView mStatusView;
MediaRecorder mRecorder;
Thread runner;
private static double mEMA = 0.0;
static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;

final Runnable updater = new Runnable(){

    public void run(){
        updateTv();
    };
};
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.noiselevel);
    mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);


    if (runner == null)
    {
        runner = new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                while (runner != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        Log.i("Noise", "Tock");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { };
                    mHandler.post(updater);
                }
            }
        };
        runner.start();
        Log.d("Noise", "start runner()");
    }
}

public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    startRecorder();
}

public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    stopRecorder();
}

public void startRecorder(){
    if (mRecorder == null)
    {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
        try
        {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        }catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
            android.util.Log.e("[Monkey]", "IOException: " +
                    android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(ioe));

        }catch (java.lang.SecurityException e) {
            android.util.Log.e("[Monkey]", "SecurityException: " +
                    android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
        try
        {
            mRecorder.start();
        }catch (java.lang.SecurityException e) {
            android.util.Log.e("[Monkey]", "SecurityException: " +
                    android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }

        //mEMA = 0.0;
    }

}
public void stopRecorder() {
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }
}

public void updateTv(){
    mStatusView.setText(Double.toString((getAmplitudeEMA())) + " dB");
}
public double soundDb(double ampl){
    return  20 * Math.log10(getAmplitudeEMA() / ampl);
}
public double getAmplitude() {
    if (mRecorder != null)
        return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude());
    else
        return 0;

}
public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
    double amp =  getAmplitude();
    mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
    return mEMA;
}
```

}

but i am very puzzled here. i whant to keep this simple... i hered about FFT and sounds so complex...

Comment: Funny, I have just used FFT. Anyway,  you want to visualize basses? So u have to think what a bass is. Ur your case u could maybe simplify that by saying its a high amplitude and a low frequenzy. I have found a FFT.java Util class, just google for it. It allows you to get the frequenzy out of the Sound information. Now you need a asynchronous Thread which is working parallel with the Sound Data and visualizes it. But sound is a big topic. You should read a few articles etc. about it. Google for "Java Sound visualizing" and you will find a tutorial for doing this in default Java. Good Luck?

Answer (score 0):

That is true audio processing is challenging. But you can use 3rd party libraries which offers some methods that you can utilize for your case.

In your case you need to detect sound pressure level and update your drawing accordingly.

Here is some libraries to detect sound pressure level.

1. [android-visualizer](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer)
2. [Tarsos DSP](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP/blob/master/src/examples/be/tarsos/dsp/example/SoundDetector.java)
3. [android-spl-meter](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-spl-meter/)